# Cassandra where clause for specific column - best approach

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, cql

I need to use where clause while searching for records with particular PID in my cassandra database

```
id = uuid
pid=  Property Id (text)
created_at = timestamp
```

I need to find the top 5 records of a particular property Id.  So my create table looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE property_tax (
    id uuid,
    state text, 
    area text,       
    balance_type text,
    created_at timestamp,
    created_by text,
    last_paid_at timestamp,
    max_tax float,
    min_tax float,
    pid text,
    prev_balance float,
    prev_interest float,
    property_type text,
    tax_cess float,
    tax_year timestamp,
    total_paid float,
    total_paid_cess float,
    total_paid_tax float,
    PRIMARY KEY (pid,created_at,id)
    );
```

and my query looks like this

```
select * from property_tax where pid = 'property1' ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Its working as per my requirement but is my approach correct? or does it need to change. Is there any performance issue which can arise in future. I am looking at 500 million records and growing.

## NEW EDIT:

I have added two column 1.state 2.area
There will be multiple areas in the state

Property ID(pid) will have multiple records not more than 100 records

```
So, I need to query TABLE property_tax for below
1. Find all the pid
2. find all the pid in the area
3. find all the pid in the state
4. find Limit 5 for pid (ORDER_BY created_at DESC)
```

Many Thanks
Shashi

Comment: 500 million pid's or ids within a single pid partition?

Comment: 5 million pid with 100 Id under each pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your always going to make the query that way add `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC);` so you don't need to reverse order read (a bit more efficient). But thats a good query for that table.

Given its 500 million pid's you mean that will work well. If its 500 million id's within a single pid you might end up with a very wide partition which has performance impacts.

Comment: I have one question: If the pid is 500 millions doesnt it mean it will create 500 million parition? I was thinking of creating PRIMARY KEY (tax_year,pid,created_at,id). So partition will be only for tax_year and all the records are within that. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: 500 million partitions is not that many, it would work. Usually around 1 to 4 billion per node it starts to impact repairs poorly (is hardware dependent). Sizing partitions are kinda funny - a lot of things will work but too large or too small and they impact performance (either reads, repairs or compactions). Really important question is how you want to query it and the cardinality of the data.

Comment: If you want to look it up by property and year then using year as your key will work, but if you want last 5 years and that would mean making 5 queries its probably better to have just the pid. Also putting all the properties for the year (500 million?) would be a very wide row and probably wont work at all so would need something else as well like state or county.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for helping me here appreciate it. I am still working out the best query for my requirement. I have added addition info int he main question can you please help me